# Different values of sampling on the same scene - cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I know that I can set different values of sampling for glossy, diffuse, etc... 
I'd like to know if there is a way to set different values for lighted spot and darker ones.
There is a lot of noise in shadows and I need an high sample value, at the same time I don't need an high value for the lighted spots so i'd like to save render time.

Ideas?